# I am getting http 404 error while try browse localhostly using apache webserver

Tags: php, apache

I installed apache server and PhP-5.2.6-win32-installer into windows server 2008.

when i try to browse d file through IE it showing an http 404 error. Apache is working on server 2008 know? Plese give me an solution.

Comment: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ , check this out it explains everithing you need to know

Comment: Please remove that code tag around the question..

Answer (score 0):

type "http://localhost" and you should be greeted by apache.. If it says nothing, then you haven't installed it properly..

Then there is another problem in windows server.. If you haven't disabled IIS server that is running by default, you'd not be allowed to run apache (i.e if you haven't changed the default port while installing apache).  So shut down IIS server through IIS manager in control panel and start apache..